# Google Play console showing app crash on Fragment$InstantiationException

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Google Play console showing app crash on Fragment$InstantiationException but i am wondring that i am not using any fragment in activity.

Here is my BaseActivity class

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Crash log is below

```
Caused by androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException:
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:628)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:57)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:483)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init> (FragmentStateManager.java:85)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState (FragmentManager.java:2728)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:198)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$2.onContextAvailable (FragmentActivity.java:149)
  at androidx.activity.contextaware.ContextAwareHelper.dispatchOnContextAvailable (ContextAwareHelper.java:99)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate (ComponentActivity.java:322)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:273)
  at com.wavesoms.mainApp.aMain.base.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.java:67)
```

I tried so much thing any and search every where but not found any solution

All answer is acceptable